# Using react-d3-map and topojson to map counties in the USA

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to map counties in the USA using [react-d3-map](https://github.com/react-d3/react-d3-map) and data from topojson. I haven't been able to get any of the examples to work from online, and think I may be missing something. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
var topojson = require('topojson');
var Map = require('react-d3-map').Map;
var PolygonGroup = require('react-d3-map').PolygonGroup;

@connect(state =>({}))
export default class ServiceAreaAppContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {'loading': true}
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({ url:"https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@1/us/10m.json"}).success(function(res){
        console.log("Response!");
        console.log(res);

        this.setState({map_info:res, loading: false});
     }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loading) {
        var test = topojson.feature(this.state.map_info, this.state.map_info.objects.counties);
        console.log(test);
        return <Map
            width= {500}
            height= {500}
            scale= {1200 * 5}
            scaleExtent= {[1 << 12, 1 << 13]}
            center= {[30.31, -97.64]}
          >
            <PolygonGroup
              key= {"polygon-test"}
              dataPolygon= {test.features}
            />
          </Map>
    } else {
        return <h4>Loading...</h4>
    }
  }
}
```

I'm able to load the data without a problem, and the I use `topojson.feature(this.state.map_info, this.state.map_info.objects.counties)` to convert the data to geojson which react-d3-map requires. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong here?